# Accurate GPS apps for smartphones available?

Tags: gps, software-recommendations, precision

I'm working on a project where we need to make accurate GPS measurements and the required precision would be in centimeter level. I've been doing some searching and not yet found any solid solutions so I make the question:

**"Are there any free accurate GPS apps available for smartphones?"**

Comment: the accuracy of the measurements will depend mainly on the smartphone, not on the app used

Comment: it´s a hardware issue, i.e. the capabilities of the GPS chips in the phone, that limits accuracy, not the software. if you want more precision, find a phone with respective GPS technology.

Comment: P.S. would you care to post your comments as answers so I can accept them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell:
Positioning/navigation apps in general only process the accuracy/precision values passed to them by the GPS module of the device, and they are primarily dependent on the capabilities of the built in GPS chipset (oviously, being indoors or near/underneath obstacles will equally effect the signal strength and thus the accuracy).
You should find sources on these parameters for the smartphone in question on the web, and there are e.g. external GPS modules that can be connected to your phone, similar to high accuracy GPS devices.
However, [this](https://www.gsa.europa.eu/newsroom/news/world-s-first-dual-frequency-gnss-smartphone-hits-market) might be highly interesting, since it seems there´s progress underway...

Answer (score 1):

There was a project some time ago, trying to port rtklib to android. I don't know if it uses special hardware, but there are affordable gps receiver which can handle rtk information. Some information can be found here: http://www.instructables.com/id/Sub-Centimeter-GPS-With-RTKLIB/

Comment: We use SXBLUE BLUETOOTH RTK GNSS receiver with CORS allows for collecting 1cm in real time. We are in the process of releasing ORANGE maps collector and GEODATA EXplorer for iOS, Android and Windows.